# css transition transform rotate bug

Tags: css

I slowly slide the mouse down over the square then the square starts to rotate after the mouse hits the edge of the square. The mouse stuck on the edge. The square begins to vibrate. How can ı fix this? I am sorry for my English.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  transition: width 1s, height 1s, transform 1s;
}

div:hover {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<br>

<div>
    <p>Hover</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZLVy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because it a square, when your on the edge inside as soon as it starts to rotate your  right away on the outside . rotation goes on/off every time the mighty mice hovers it and don't anymore .

As a work around, you could shape it as a round and draw inside a square to avoid this :

possible example to start from

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
box-sizing:border-box;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding:25px;
  margin:-20px 0 0  -20px;
  border-radius:50%;
/* background color rgba(0,0,0,0.001) added so it is not totaly transparent and can catch the hover some browsers might need it  ... */
  background: linear-gradient(red,red) rgba(0,0,0,0.001) center center/ 70% 70% no-repeat;
  transition:  1s;
}

div:hover {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  padding:50px;
  margin:-35px  0 0 -35px;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<br>

<div>
    <p>Hover</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I thought this but I didn't know how to do. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You get this behavior since the :hover check is on the element that is rotating. So when the cursor is on the edge it will enter and leave the :hover state back and forth. The key is then to check for :hover on something which is stationary instead.

I think you can rotate a child element and check for hover on its parent. So the hover check isn't on what's rotating.

So in this case wrap it in another div and check for hover there.

Example

```css
.parent:hover .child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

It might be easier to execute via script, I vaguely remember running into a similar issue way back and ended up solving it via onmouseover event instead.

Comment: Yes I agree, using script easier way for this issue.